# How to parse JSON Data from a network and save it into Flutter SQFLite database?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am able to load JSON data from a network and display it in a `ListView` directly without caching it in a database, meaning without network connection I cannot load the list again. So being a newbie in Flutter, I would like to find a way to save the data in a database for offline support.

Here is the JSON parsing method that queries cities from the network:

```
 getCities() async {
 var id;
 var name;
 var code;
 var district;
 var population;
 var jsonData = await http.get(BASE_URL);

 List cities = json.decode(jsonData.body);
 debugPrint('Response is $cities');

 List<City> cityList = cities.map((map) => City.fromJson(map)).toList();
 for (var city in cityList) {
 id = city.cityId;
 name = city.cityName;
 code = city.countryCode;
 district = city.cityDistrict;
 population = city.cityPopulation;
 print('Name is $name. and Id is $id');


 City cityObject = City(cityId: id,
    cityName: name,
    countryCode: code,
    cityDistrict: district,
     cityPopulation: population);
 WorldCitiesDatabaseHelper().insertCities(cityObject);
 }
```

Here is the Insert function in database

```
Future<void> insertCities(City city) async{
var database =  _database;

await database.insert(citiesTable, city.toJson(), conflictAlgorithm:
ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
}
```

This is my PODO class model

```
class City {
 String cityId;
 String cityName;
 String countryCode;
 String cityDistrict;
 String cityPopulation;

 City(
  {this.cityId,
  this.cityName,
  this.countryCode,
  this.cityDistrict,
  this.cityPopulation});

 City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
 cityId = json['id'];
 cityName = json['name'];
 countryCode = json['code'];
 cityDistrict = json['district'];
 cityPopulation = json['population'];
}

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
if (cityId != null) {
  data['id'] = cityId;
}
data['name'] = this.cityName;
data['code'] = this.countryCode;
data['district'] = this.cityDistrict;
data['population'] = this.cityPopulation;
return data;
 }
}
```

This is the error in log cat

```
2019-06-21 15:42:56.362 20889-21014/com.sirikye.world_cities I/flutter: Name 
is Zwickau. and Id is 3145
2019-06-21 15:42:56.362 20889-21014/com.sirikye.world_cities I/flutter: Name 
is Zwolle. and Id is 28
2019-06-21 15:42:56.362 20889-21014/com.sirikye.world_cities I/flutter: Name 
is Zytomyr. and Id is 3446
2019-06-21 15:42:56.362 20889-21014/com.sirikye.world_cities I/flutter: Name 
is [San CristÃ³bal de] la Laguna. and Id is 698
2019-06-21 15:42:56.365 20889-21014/com.sirikye.world_cities E/flutter: 
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'insert' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: insert("cities", _LinkedHashMap len:5, conflictAlgorithm: 
Instance of 'ConflictAlgorithm')
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      WorldCitiesDatabaseHelper.insertCities 
(package:Cities/database/world_cities_database_helper.dart:54:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      getCities (package:Cities/home.dart:78:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HomePage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:Cities/home.dart:43:11)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap 
(package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
```

And this is my JSON response from the API

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Kabul","code":"AFG","district":"Kabol","population":"1780000"}, 
{"id":"2","name":"Qandahar","code":"AFG","district":"Qandahar","population":"237500"},{"id":"3","name":"Herat","code":"AFG","district":"Herat","population":"186800"}]
```

Comment: There's an in-depth guide in the flutter docs of how to persist data using SQLite: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite
Also, the connectivity plugin let's you decide wether you're online or not, so in case you're not online you can simply pull from the local DB: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity

Comment: @Philip Feldman I have edited the question to the right context hope you understand me now.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

> 1 call api

```
Map result = await GetUserInfo.callApi("YOUR URL");
      if (result["errorCode"] == "0") {
        UserModel userModel = result["value"];
        String userName = userModel.name;
      } else {
        String error = result["msg"];
        print(error);
        isError = true;
      }
```

> 2 parse data

```
class GetUserInfo{
  static Future callApi(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: Config.httpGetHeader);
    final statusCode = response.statusCode;
    try {
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        Map body = json.decode(response.body);
          List arrayList=body['array'];
           List<UserModel> categoryModelList =categories.map((c) => new UserModel.fromMap(c)).toList();
          return {
            'errorCode': "0",
            'value': categoryModelList,
          };

      } else {
        return {'errorCode': "-1", 'msg': "Status Code Error"};
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return {'errorCode': "-1", 'msg': "$e"};
    }
  }
}
```

> 3 user model

```
class UserModel {

var id,name,code,district,population

UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
    code = map['code'];
    district = map['district'];
    population = map['population'];   } }
```

Comment: Thanks @Vithani Ravi for that precise approach but you did not highlight on how to insert the values in the database using the model object and instance of the database class. Checkout my insertCities method and how am implementing it in the getCities method, second last line. I think that is were am going wrong.

Comment: List<UserModel> categoryModelList =categories.map((c) => new UserModel.fromMap(c)).toList(); here pass fromMap in model after UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
    code = map['code'];
    district = map['district'];
    population = map['population'];   } }